# Compiling as AnyCPU produces assembly with 32BIT flag set on 64-bit machine

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5, 32bit-64bit, anycpu

I've created a brand new .NET 4.5 WinForm project in Visual Studio 2013 on a 64-bit machine. After compiling, I run corflags in the .exe and the 32BIT flag is set.

```
Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 131075
ILONLY    : 1
32BIT     : 1
Signed    : 0
```

When I take a look at Task Manager, it's also marked as a 32 bit process.

I didn't add any references that would maybe force it to run in 32-bit mode. I took a look at the project file and didn't spot anything suspicious either.

I can run `corflags /32BIT-` on the assembly and it runs just fine as a 64-bit process.

What could be causing it to compile as a 32-bit executable?

Comment: Do you have the `Prefer32Bit` MSBuild property set somewhere in a `.csproj` file?

Comment: In the project properties there's a tab called "Build". Under the "Platform target" field is the "Prefer 32-bit" field. Could that be what you need to change?

Comment: @AndyJ I didn't know that property existed. Turning that off and rebuilding fixes the issue for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the project Property Pages is a page called "Build" (A).

Under the "Platform Target" field (B), is the "Prefer 32bit" field (C).

You can toggle that to remove the 32bit flag from the corflags.

[image: Prefer 32bit]
(Image from VS 2015)